# Lifetime of fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my application, I have multiple activities and fragments. I know that when application is in background, system may destroy the activities. But, is it also possible that system destroys only a fragment and not its activity? My, understanding is that only complete activities are destroyed by the system but I am not able to find a concrete answer. Please help

Answer (score 1):

The fragment's lifecycle is directly affected by the host activity lifecycle, as stated 
[here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

What that means is that the fragment will be destroyed/paused etc only when that happens to the host activity too. So the answer is no, the system will not kill your fragment if your activity is on the foreground.

Also consider this: a fragment is a component of your activity. A UI component is also
part of an activity. If the system were to kill a fragment it would be like "killing" a
Button on your UI.

Comment: "So the answer is no, the system will not kill your fragment if your activity is on the foreground." -- Just to be clear, I am talking about the case when app is in background.

Comment: Again, the same rules apply. The system will call onDestroy() on your fragment when it does that for your Activity too.

Comment: "For example, when the activity is paused, so are all fragments in it, and when the activity is destroyed, so are all fragments." http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html check second paragraph.